# Summing Row Value in Nested List

Tags: python, data-analysis

I just started learning python, And got stuck in this question:

I have this list :

```
data = [
    ['Grinning', 2.26, 1.02, 87.3],
    ['Beaming', 19.1, 1.69, 150.0],
    ['ROFL', 25.6, 0.774, 0.0],
    ['Tears of Joy', 233.0, 7.31, 2270.0],
    ['Winking', 15.2, 2.36, 264.0],
    ['Happy', 22.7, 4.26, 565.0],
    ['Heart Eyes', 64.6, 11.2, 834.0],
    ['Kissing', 87.5, 5.13, 432.0],
    ['Thinking', 6.81, 0.636, 0.0],
    ['Unamused', 6.0, 0.236, 478.0],
    ['Sunglasses', 4.72, 3.93, 198.0],
    ['Loudly Crying', 24.7, 1.35, 654.0],
    ['Kiss Mark', 21.7, 2.87, 98.7],
    ['Two Hearts', 10.0, 5.69, 445.0],
    ['Heart', 118.0, 26.0, 1080.0],
    ['Heart Suit', 3.31, 1.82, 697.0],
    ['Thumbs Up', 23.1, 3.75, 227.0],
    ['Shrugging', 1.74, 0.11, 0.0],
    ['Fire', 4.5, 2.49, 150.0],
    ['Recycle', 0.0333, 0.056, 932.0]
]
```

I need to sum up each row of numbers, for example:

```
"Grinning" sum = 2.26 + 1.02 + 87.3
```

I tried a lot of ways to get only the row numbers But didn't found a way that would work correctly and will not sum up all of the columns

I tried this also:

```
totalemoji = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    for i in range(1, 3):
        totalemoji += data[1][i] + data[1][i] + data[1][i]
print(totalemoji)
```

but it prints a number that I don't even recognize...

I would appreciate if someone can explain how to sum each row numbers

Comment: use list comprehension , `[[x[0],sum(x[1:])] for x in data]`, output will be a list of lists, with each sub list contains `[first element, sum of rest of elements]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1: Without `sum` as Requested***

```
d = {}

for current_sub_list in data:
    current_list_sum = 0
    for j in range(1, len(current_sub_list)):
        current_list_sum += current_sub_list[j]
    d[current_sub_list[0]] = current_list_sum

print(d)
```

***Option 2:***

```
d = {}

for x in data:
    d[x[0]] = sum(x[1:])

print(d)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that without the sum?, Also what is enumerate?

Comment: enumerate lets you go over the values (`x`) of a list (`data`) and keep tracking your current index (`i`)

Comment: @GalIsrael Added another solution without `sum`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
[sum(i[1:]) for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
    
    x.append([data[i][0], sum(data[i][1:])])
    
print(x)
```

Here x is a `list` of `list`